# Java Persistence JPA: Many to one relationship is not reflected in entity?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, h2

I have the following 2 `h2` tables and `JPA` entities:

```
Trainer

Client
```

**SQL:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TRAINER;
CREATE TABLE TRAINER (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CLIENT;
CREATE TABLE CLIENT (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
trainer_id INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENT_TRAINER_ID FOREIGN KEY (trainer_id) REFERENCES TRAINER(id)
);
```

**Trainer Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRAINER")
public class Trainer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "trainer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Client> clients;
    
    public Trainer() {}
    
    @JsonManagedReference
    public List<Client> getClients() {
        return clients;
    }

    public void setClients(List<Client> clients) {
        this.clients = clients;
    }
    
    // other getters and setters
    
    }
```

**Client Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENT")
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "trainer_id")
    private Trainer trainer;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    public Trainer getTrainer() {
        return trainer;
    }

    public void setTrainer(Trainer trainer) {
        this.trainer = trainer;
    }
    
    // other getters and setters
    
}
```

When I hit my endpoint to get all trainers, the list of clients also comes as expected.

However when I try to get all clients, the response `does not` contain the trainer object within it.

Why is this? I am potentially using the `@JsonManagedReference` incorrectly?

Edit:
When I remove the back reference from client I get:

```
Request processing failed: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)] with root cause
```

When I add `@JsonIdentityInfo` as suggested I get:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: 
No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor 
and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer 
(to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) 
(through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]
->com.example.model.Client["trainer"]
->com.example.model.Trainer$HibernateProxy$MCJQCpAj["clients"]
->org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentBag[0]->com.example.model.Client$HibernateProxy$4n0KbuYf["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working as it's supposed to.  From the documentation for `@JsonBackReference`

> Annotation used to indicate that associated property is part of
> two-way linkage between fields; and that its role is "child" (or
> "back") link. Value type of the property must be a bean: it can not be
> a Collection, Map, Array or enumeration. Linkage is handled such that
> the property annotated with this annotation is not serialized;

The last sentence states that properties annotated with `@JsonBackReference` are not serialized.

You can use `@JsonIdentityInfo` to pull this off.

At the class level on both Client and Trainer, add

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
```

Here is what the Trainer model looks like:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRAINER")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Trainer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "trainer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Here is the Client model

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENT")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "trainer_id")
    private Trainer trainer;
}
```

Here's a simple test that proves out the behavior, with persistence:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.terrafirmaeng.example.persistence.TrainerRepository;
import com.terrafirmaeng.example.persistence.ClientRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
class ClientTest {

    @Autowired
    TrainerRepository trainerRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    ClientRepository clientRepository;
    

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectWriter objectWriter = objectMapper.writerFor(Client.class);

        Trainer trainer = new Trainer();
        trainer.setName("trainer");

        Client clientA = new Client();
        clientA.setTrainer(trainer);
        clientA.setName("clientA");

        Client clientB = new Client();
        clientB.setTrainer(trainer);
        clientB.setName("clientB");

        trainer.getClients().add(clientA);
        trainer.getClients().add(clientB);
        Trainer persistedTrainer = trainerRepository.save(trainer);

        clientRepository.findAll().forEach(client -> {
            try {
                System.out.println(objectWriter.writeValueAsString(client));
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
{"id":2,"name":"clientA","trainer" {"id":1,"name":"trainer","clients":[2,{"id":3,"name":"clientB","trainer":1}]}}
{"id":3,"name":"clientB","trainer":{"id":1,"name":"trainer","clients":[{"id":2,"name":"clientA","trainer":1},3]}}
```

Comment: thanks, how should I model this then so that both fields are serialized within each entity? I.e. the trainer will come back for each client. I added the error that I get when I remove the back reference annotation from client entity

Comment: @java12399900 I'm guessing that you arrived here because you were getting a circular reference during serialization.  As you've found, managed reference won't work because the back reference is excluded.  You can either use `@JsonView` and build the views, or use `@JsonIdentityInfo` which will only provide you with the id of the entity.  The other option is to write your own serializer.  IMO, your best option is to consider hateoas where you get back the trainer as a link reference.

Comment: Can you please share in answer how to use @JsonIdentityInfo as I am getting another error when I try to implement it. Is this a design flaw that I have in terms of the circular dependency?

Comment: @java12399900 see my updates to the answer.

Comment: thanks, should the back reference be removed totally? When remove it and add the identity info annotation I get the error I have updated in my original question

Comment: @java12399900 Yes you do not need to use ManagedReference and BackReference.  See the updates to the answer to see what the model looks like, and an updated test that actually persists the objects, retrieves the persisted Clients and outputs their serialized values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252242/discussion-between-lane-maxwell-and-java12399900).